# Using Selenium to get information within the tag 'h1' and id

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping, webdriverwait

I'm trying to get the information which is: 'Jarrow Formulas, Methyl Folate, 400 mcg, 60 Veggie Caps'

you can check the picture, thank you so much:

[image]

[image]

I used this code but it doesnt work out:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get("https://www.iherb.com/c/Vitamin-B?sr=2")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

item_name = list()

#close the pop up
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"svg[data-ga-event-action='list-close']"))).click()

#store all the links in a list
item_links = [item.get_attribute("href") for item in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".absolute-link-wrapper > a.product-link")))]

for item_link in item_links:
    driver.get(item_link)item_name.append(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[id="name"]').text) #this code doesnt work
```

Comment: Instead of using [id="name"], try using #name maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print the *text* `value` you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `xpath` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//section[@class='column image-fixed']//following::section[2]//div[@id='product-summary-header']//h1[@id='name']").text)
  ```
- Using `xpath` and `get_attribute()`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//section[@class='column image-fixed']//following::section[2]//div[@id='product-summary-header']//h1[@id='name']").get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Jarrow Formulas, Methyl Folate, 400 mcg, 60 Veggie Caps
  ```

---

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `xpath` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  driver.get('https://ca.iherb.com/pr/Jarrow-Formulas-Methyl-Folate-400-mcg-60-Veggie-Caps/42778')
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//section[@class='column image-fixed']//following::section[2]//div[@id='product-summary-header']//h1[@id='name']"))).text)
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and `get_attribute()`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://ca.iherb.com/pr/Jarrow-Formulas-Methyl-Folate-400-mcg-60-Veggie-Caps/42778')
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//section[@class='column image-fixed']//following::section[2]//div[@id='product-summary-header']//h1[@id='name']"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Jarrow Formulas, Methyl Folate, 400 mcg, 60 Veggie Caps
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240245/how-to-retrieve-the-text-of-a-webelement-using-selenium-python/55241232#55241232)

---

### References

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium/55902072#55902072)

Comment: Hello @DebanjanB:
I just posted a question related to the Selenium. Please help to check, I really appreciate it.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66073388/optimizing-python-web-scraping-script-with-selenium